# Why does select on a named pipe with no writers block indefinitely?

Tags: c++, linux, select, posix, nonblocking

I call select with a single named pipe fd in read_fds. This named pipe has no writers and has only been opened in non-blocking, read only mode. I would expect that the select returns with the named pipe fd marked as ready to read, and that trying to read from the pipe returns 0:

From the manpage on read:

> When attempting to read from an empty pipe or FIFO:
>
> - If no process has the pipe open for writing, read() shall return 0 to > indicate end-of-file.

However, select just blocks indefinitely. Why is this the case?

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <stdexcept>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char buf[4096];

    // Create a named pipe
    auto err = mkfifo("/tmp/whatever",0666);
    if(err) {
        throw std::runtime_error(
                    std::string("Failed to create fifo ")+
                    strerror(errno));
    }

    std::thread reader_thread(
                [&](){
        auto fd = open("/tmp/whatever",O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK);
        if(fd < 0) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to open fifo");
        }

        fd_set fds;
        while(1) {
            FD_ZERO(&fds);
            FD_SET(fd,&fds);
            std::cerr << "calling select" << std::endl;
            auto retval = select(fd+1,&fds,nullptr,nullptr,nullptr);
            if(retval < 0) {
                std::runtime_error("Failed to call select");
            }

            if(FD_ISSET(fd,&fds)) {
                auto read_bytes = read(fd,buf,4096);
                std::cerr << "read " << read_bytes << std::endl;
                if(read_bytes==0) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        close(fd);
    });

    reader_thread.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't spam tags! C is not C++ is not C!

Comment: Why should `select` return if there is nothing to read??

Comment: @Olaf> because the select's manual page explicitly states that *“a file descriptor is also ready on end-of-file”* while the fifo man page also says that *“If all file descriptors referring to the write end of a pipe have been closed,  then an  attempt  to  read(2) from the pipe will see end-of-file”*. It is actually a good question.

Comment: I don't see an openend pipe is at EOF when never opened for write. That would just open doors widely for race-conditions between opening on both sides!

Comment: @Stargateur> because the manpage of select says the exact condition watched by select is *“to see if a read (2) will not block”*?

Comment: @Olaf> That's what I was thinking, probably before the first open it would just block and not show end-of-file. This is an interesting edge case that's not really well documented, and that's why I think the question is a good one. - plus it does provide a MCVE.

Comment: Any reason for removing the C++ tag? Your code apparently is C++. Rolled back.

Comment: @spectras: Which could be easily checked by a simple `echo` or similar. That would be worth a DV for no research; too bad I'm out of votes for now.

Comment: Finally, I think that call select on file in non blocking mode don't make sense.

Comment: @Stargateur: I disagree. That would allow to read more than what#s currently in the buffer. If the call was blocking, `read` would wait until all data is available. So either one reads byte-wise (inefficient) from a blocking pipe or in larger chunks.

Comment: @Olaf Oh, yes in this case, this make sense but that force select to not return if there are nothing to read. Or to not set as true if there are no data in the fd. What is the current behavior for select for non blocking fd ? I don't find any clear documentation.

Comment: @Stargateur: I wonder what the `timeout` argument to `select` is for ... :-)

Comment: I updated my answer to explain the missing EOF condition. Maybe that is worth not only the acceptance, but also an upvote ;-)

Comment: @spectras: "If all file descriptors referring to the write end of a pipe have been closed, then an attempt to read(2) from the pipe will see end-of-file" - I think my answer now explains the problem. Details are important. Constructive critique is welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the POSIX documentation fo `select`:

> A descriptor shall be considered ready for reading when a call to an input function with O_NONBLOCK clear would not block, whether or not the function would transfer data successfully. (The function might return data, an end-of-file indication, or an error other than one indicating that it is blocked, and in each of these cases the descriptor shall be considered ready for reading.
>
> ...
>
> If none of the selected descriptors are ready for the requested operation, the pselect() or select() function shall block until at least one of the requested operations becomes ready, **until the timeout occurs**, or until interrupted by a signal.

From the `pipe(7)` manpage (which is the underlying object of a FIFO):

> If all file descriptors referring to the write end of a pipe **have been closed**, then an attempt to read(2) from the pipe will see end-of-file (read(2) will return 0).

Mind the usage of present perfect tense! This implies the FIFO has to be opened on both sides **fiorst**, the closed on the writer side (for your application) to generate an `EOF` condition.

So, unless the fifo is eventually closed by the writer, why should `select` return? The setting for the (fifo-)file itself is irrelevant for good reason: It would introduce a race-condition between opening on both sides when using the most efficient method to read more than one byte at a time. That's the normal way for e.g. a command pipe: start the reader process and lateron the writer (which is typically a completely unrelated program when using a named pipe).

If you want `select` to return early, use the `timeout` argument. But normally, one uses a seperate thread which can be terminated by a signal (see the `select` man-page for more information).

As a sidenote: One nice thing about Linux/POSIX is that it does not really matter whether you use a FIFO or a file or your microphone driver.

Comment: Dam, I just found that ! http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/

Comment: @Stargateur: not sure what you mean; I just get a global page. The information above is from the Linux manpages (3). I intentionally did not use the Linux-specific commands (cross-checking did not reveal relevant diffferences). I hope it is all correct, I just had a short peek at the man-pages; that is normally not the area I work on.

Comment: Oh, the man page on my system don't show that... but you right https://linux.die.net/man/3/select. I don't really mean anything just that I found this documentation (that answer the question) on the same time that you answered. So I feel like I search for nothing :p.

Comment: @Stargateur: You either have a bugged distro, or forgot to install the `man-all` (or `all-man` or similar) package :-)

Comment: Yeah the reason makes sense, especially as otherwise it would be impossible to wait for first writer except by doing a busy loop. It's just odd the documentation isn't more explicit, and I hope your answer finds a good spot in search engine results.

Comment: @spectras: Actually the documentation contains all information. It is just a bit sprinkled because actually the question touches multiple functions. If one is used to Linux/Unix being more like Lego with small versatile building blocks, it is fine. It is just not a monolithic, specialised API like the Windows way. Personally I like it.